# django: syntax of return HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, httpresponse

I'm trying to pass two variables into a HttpResonseRedirect, but it won't work. I get a "TypeError, not all arguments converted during string formatting" I think my problem might be that my syntax is wrong, since it works if I just pass one variable. What's the proper syntax for passing in two or more?

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/labels/get/%s/%s/' % store_id, order_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple python string formatting issue:

```
'/labels/get/%s/%s/' % store_id, order_id
```

should be

```
'/labels/get/%s/%s/' % (store_id, order_id)
```

Since there are 2 arguments the string is expecting, you need to specify the arguments as a tuple.

So, the response would look like this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/labels/get/%s/%s/' % (store_id, order_id))
```